# Gitlab - disable interactive mode conflict resolution

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, merge-conflict-resolution

After every release we merge the release branch back into master.

I noticed though that when there are merge conflicts between a release branch and master, an additional commit is added on top of the release branch (even if these are protected branches!).

- How can I prevent this behavior?
- If it's not possible to do so how can I disable the interactive mode UI used by Gitlab for conflicts resolutions so that devs can only resolve conflicts locally?

(I can't find this option in the settings or in Gitlab documentation.)

---

UPDATE:

Protecting the release branches actually does disable the interactive conflict resolution UI for devs without write access.

In my case the problem was that the regex applied to the protected branches was incorrect.

The issue of dirty commits on top of the source branch still occurs though..

---

**Potential Solution** to test: *Fast Forward Merge option* in *Merge Methods*

[image]

Comment: It is called Rebase, here is my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253700/how-to-stop-getting-extra-merge-commit-every-time

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf is the solution that you/re suggesting the one appended to my question? Thx